# How to use of Firebase Real Time Database to save Users Info?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to save some info form my users in Firebase database. I did it like this:

```
 FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
  DatabaseReference mRootReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
  DatabaseReference mHeadingRefrence = mRootReference.child("heading");

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    headign = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

        String h = headign.getText().toString();
        mHeadingRefrence.setValue(h);
        headign.setText("");

      }
    });
  }
```

But when Users send this String to my Firebase, their info will be replaced at first row!, but I want to save this String from all of the users.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Becase Firebase is a NoSQL database which is structured as pairs of key and values, every node in the database is a `Map`. So in case of a `Map`, when you add data as you do, it replaces the old value with the new one.

So in order to achieve this, you need to use a `unique identifier`. So you need to change this line of code:

```
mHeadingRefrence.setValue(h);
```

with

```
mHeadingRefrence.push().setValue(h);
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer.